# Gradle Artifactory Plugin Not Generating Pom File

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifactory

A weird issue is occurring when I try to "artifactoryPublish" to a remote artifactory repository.

I have the task run

```
./gradlew clean jar artifactoryPublish
```

Which worked only a couple days ago. Now I am getting this error:

```
:artifactoryPublish FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':artifactoryPublish'.
> File '/Users/me/Programming/android/LibraryPlugin/build/poms/pom-default.xml'      specified for property 'mavenDescriptor' does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more      log output.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might as well run with the --stacktrace option to get more information.

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the similar issue, I had optimised the gradle.properties for fast compiling.

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Removing them once and compiling the code worked, you can add them back once the pom is generated.

Most probably "parallel=true" was the culprit.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Holy moly this was helpful! For me I needed to disable `configureondemand`.

Comment: awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. Adding org.gradle.configureondemand=true helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle build snippet in the question could be useful, but if I have to blindly guess, I bet that you don't have `maven` or `maven-publish` plugin applied (or you applied the wrong one).

Comment: I have same issue using ```android-maven``` like in the gradle-android-aar example.  I submitted an issue to the plugin repo > https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-plugin/issues/17.

Comment: @JBaruch, I am also getting a similar error but I do have maven and maven-publish plugin applied.

Comment: @Jason that deserves a separate question with your build script in it.

Comment: @JBaruch: This error seems to be an issue with gradle 2.4 and above. https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/GAP-174

Answer (score 2):

We had this same issue after upgrading our Gradle version but found it was an issue with using old settings for the com.github.dcendents.android-maven plugin. To resolve the issue we removed the configure block and instead created a task to create the pom-defaults.xml file.  Here's the relevant parts of our gradle file:

```
task writeNewPom {
    pom {
        project {
            packaging 'aar'
            name 'Some Name'
            url 'http://www.example.com'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("$buildDir/poms/pom-default.xml")
}

artifactoryPublish {
    dependsOn assembleRelease
    dependsOn sourcesJar
    dependsOn writeNewPom
}
```

Comment: For this to be working, you need to wrap the whole pom block inside a `doLast{}` block.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom plugin in my AS project. I changed the version of gradle in custom plugin to the same version I am using in AS. Then,I executed the command via terminal rather than running from AS. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I solved it by simply running the task:

```
./gradlew generatePomFileForWarPublishPublication
```

Provided by the artifactory plugin.

Answer (score -2):

This problem can simply be solved by publishing through command line
instead of through Android Studio
 `./gradlew clean module_name:artifactoryPublish`
[Link] https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/17